# Display subcategories in the filter on CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins

I have a little problem with my CPT. I created some categories with subcategories, and **I wish display the subcategories in the select filter**. Actually, the categories filter display only the first level of categories. I use this plugin, [Custom Content Type Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-content-type-manager/).

Categories filter:

[image]

Categories list:

[image]

Thank you in advance for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook in to the Posts list table using the `manage_posts_extra_tablenav` filter, but you can show the filter yourself by using the `wp_dropdown_categories()` function.

The only two `$args` that you are really interested in are `depth` and `taxonomy`, but I've included all of the defaults below.

Full details of the [`wp_dropdown_categories()` function can be found in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories)

```
add_filter('manage_posts_extra_tablenav', 'my_add_category_dropdown');
function my_add_category_dropdown(){

    $args = array(
        'show_option_all'    => '',
        'show_option_none'   => '',
        'option_none_value'  => '-1',
        'orderby'            => 'ID', 
        'order'              => 'ASC',
        'show_count'         => 0,
        'hide_empty'         => 1, 
        'child_of'           => 0,
        'exclude'            => '',
        'echo'               => 1,
        'selected'           => 0,
        'hierarchical'       => 0, 
        'name'               => 'cat',
        'id'                 => '',
        'class'              => 'postform',
        'depth'              => 0,
        'tab_index'          => 0,
        'taxonomy'           => 'category',
        'hide_if_empty'      => false,
        'value_field'        => 'term_id',  
    );
    wp_dropdown_categories($args);

}
```